# two xslt list vew webparts

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part

Is it possible to send different parameters like "rootfolder" (usually fount in the url as a get-parameter) to two different xslt list view webparts on one single page? How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to send _rootfolder_ to both LVWP1 and LVWP2 or send e.g. _rootfolder_ to LVWP2 and _subfolder_ to LVWP1?

Comment: A little bit more complex. I want to send rootfolder=A to LVWP1 and rootfolder=B to LVWP2. Another possible solution could be to send rootfolder=a to LVWP1 and afterwards rootfolder=B to LVWP2. In th second option LVWP1 must remember that it's rootfolder was set to A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is but you'd need the Query String Filter web part which comes with the SharePoint Server Enterprise licence.

Or otherwise you might be able to do it in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to add a kind of "memory" to an xslt webpart and let it remember which parameters have been passed to it last time by the current user?

Answer (score 0):

You have the ability to establish connections between LVWP's and other data-connectivity wepbarts.

By using this functionality you could create a new webpart which could read the parameters sent and then forward them to the two LVWP's.

[Here's a guide on how to do so.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/ConnectingCustomWebParts.aspx)

Comment: Does LVWP cosume it's parameters as a consumer-webpart exactly the same way it's via url? Like "rootfolder" for example?